# Cayley Table Question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cayley-table

How can I figure out the order of the elements in a Cayley table?

Answer (score 4):

A Cayley table does multiplication for you.

To compute powers of $x$, first look at the row and column for $x$: this gives you $x^2$.

To get $x^3$, find the row for $x$ and the column for $x^2$. (Or you can do the column for $x$ and the row for $x^2$.) This gets you $x^3$.

Adapt this to do greater powers of $x$.

Then you just need to count how many steps it takes you to reach the identity element, and you have the order.